# inserting a string at the end of a line

Tags: c++

So Im making this program where it adds comments to any code that I want but it has to look for the string `"// var"` to know that there is a variable on the line below it. What I'm trying to do in this function is erase the initial line that has `"// var"` then add it to the end of the very next line. I'm searching for all of this in a string a called `file` which contain all the contents of the file. after everything is changed, I output it to a new revised file which is declared as `oF`.

```
void addVariable(string& file, ofstream& oF)   

size_t pos = 0;
string variableString = "// var";

while(( pos = file.find("// var", pos)) != string::npos )
{
    file.erase(pos,8);
    file.insert(pos,"// var" );
    pos += pos.length();
}       
    oF<<file;
```

My issue is with `file.insert`. I cant seem to figure out any way to place `"// var"` at the end of the line

Here's an example of what should change between the initial file and the revised file

```
//var
int number;
```

to

```
int numbers; //var
```

Also using `std`

Comment: Is not it better to load the file, and save a new file with the new changes?

Comment: Im sorry do you think you could explain a little more

Comment: It is exceedingly difficult to insert text into the middle of a file without overwriting what is already there. You have to move everything in the file after the insertion point over to free up space for the insertion. It is better to read the file up to the insertion point into a temporary file, make the insert into the temporary file, read the rest of the input file into the temporary, close both files, then replace the input file with the temporary.

Comment: ^ So, read the entire file line by line. On each line you read, write it into a completely new file. If the line you read is a `// var`, then skip it (means don't write it to the new file) but make sure to add `// var` at the end of the next line(set a boolean flag ToAdd or NotToAdd, and raise it - make it true - whenever you need to add); And continue to the next line... etc. Now these are abstract designs of what you would need to implement, research a solution for each step if you don't know how to do that step.

Comment: Alright thank you so much. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

- Open the InputFile
- Open some OutputFile
- (process): Read a Line into a `string CurrentLine`
- `If(CurrentLine == "// var")` -> `ToAdd = true; continue;`
- `Else`, `If(ToAdd == true)` -> `CurrentLine += " // var"; ToAdd = false;`
- Write `CurrentLine` to the Output File
- Continue to the next line (repeat process)
- Once all lines were read and processed, close both files and replace the old with the new

Research steps for implementation.